# How to test a named CheckConstraint or ValidationError is raised in unittests?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest, django-testing, django-tests

I am unittesting validations and checkconstraints on my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=~Q(title='Word'),
            name='title_cannot_be_word'
        ),

    def clean(self):
       error_dict = {}
            if self.title == 'Word':
                error_dict['title'] = 'Title can not be Word'

       if error_dict:
            raise ValidationError(error_dict)
```

In my tests.py:

```
def test_validation(self):

    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        m = MyModel(title='Word')
        m.clean()

def test_constraint(self):

    with self.assertRaises(Integrity):
        m = MyModel.objects.create(title='Word')
```

This all works fine, however in practice I have multiple `CheckConstraints` and `ValidationErrors` for different fields, so I want to be able to test that the correct error has been raised.

How can I test a named `CheckConstraint` like `title_cannot_be_word` is raised, or a named `ValidationError` like `error_dict['title']` is raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a reference to the exception, and then continue validating:

```
def test_validation(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as ex:
        m = MyModel(title='Word')
        m.clean()
    exception = ex.exception
    self.assertTrue(hasattr(exception, 'error_dict'))
    self.assertIn('title', exception.error_dict)
```

As for an `IntegrityError`, this does not contain any fields, it is just `Exception` with parameters. You might want to check if the name of the exception is in the string representation:

```
def test_constraint(self):
    with self.assertRaises(Integrity) as ex:
        MyModel.objects.create(title='Word')
    exception = ex.exception
    self.assertIn('title_cannot_be_word', str(exception))
```

Comment: assuming you had a code in your `ValidationError` (e.g. `ValidationError('message', code='mycode')`) how would you test for this? I can't find it in `ex.exception` or `ex.code`?

Comment: Thanks, that gives `'ValidationError' object has no attribute 'code'`. In the `clean()` method I can `print(error_dict['title'].code)` which returns the code, but in the test I the `AttributeError` when using `print(ex.exception.code)`. Is this a quirk of how `assertRaises` works?

Comment: ... `ex.exception.code.__dict__` only shows `{'error_dict':{'title':[ValidationError(['Title can not be word'])]}}`?

Comment: @alias51: ah, but you added an error? What about `ex.exception.error_dict['title'][0].code`?